# Rails Polymorphic Association - Pulling commenter name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I've got a polymorphic association setup for my comments. Its finally working and saving all the data properly it seems. I can't get across the relationship to pull out the commenter name though.

```
<div class="span5">
  <%= comment.commenter.name %>
  <%= comment.body %>
</div>
```

The data's correct in my database for the comment. Commenter corresponds to the user_id.

```
<Comment id: 9, commenter: 2, subject: nil, body: "whaa", commentable_id: 1, commentable_type: "User", created_at: "2012-09-11 14:58:36", updated_at: "2012-09-11 14:58:36">
```

Here's models:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  attr_accessible :body, :commentable_id, :commentable_type, :commenter, :subject

end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:body].blank? }

end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Comment`'s `:commenter` is a foreign key for `User`'s `:id` column, you need to define this relationship in your `Comment` model

```
belongs_to :commenter, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :commenter
```

and the other side in your `User` model

```
has_many :authored_comments, class_name: "Comment"
```

Now you can access all of the `Comment`s a `User` has written

```
u = User.find(some_id)
u.authored_comments
```

the comments associated with the `User` *(potentially written by others)*

```
u.comments
```

and the author of some `Comment`

```
c = Comment.find(some_id)
c.commenter
c.commenter.name # their :name attribute
```

Comment: Works great! Now I have both belongs_to associations in Comment. And prior in my Comment controller create action I was saving current_user.id as commenter, I changed this to just current_user and now everything's perfect.